# Possible to store templated lambda into std::function?

Tags: c++, c++20

with C++20, we get templated lambdas to do things like that:

```
    auto t = []<typename T>(T tmp){std::cout << tmp << std::endl;};
```

But what if I need to specify the exact type via std::function<>? (don't rely on auto).

Is it possible to store the templated lambda into a `std::function<>` wrapper? e.g. similar to the following?

```
    template<typename T>
    std::function<void(T)>  t = []<typename T>(T tmp){std::cout << tmp << std::endl;};
```

and use it like a regular template-function?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Note that generic lambdas aren't new in C++20, we've had them since C++14, it's just the specific spelling is new.

Comment: isn't `auto` a "templated" lambda? like `auto t = [](auto tmp){std::cout << tmp << std::endl;};`

Comment: I want to add the lambda into a class as a non-static member.
And therefore, it must not be defined with auto.

Comment: Can't catch the point! "But what if I need to specify the exact type?" The exact type of the parameter(s) for the lambda/function call? If so, why we need a template/auto inside the lambda definition?

Comment: I don't want to say `auto t = templated lambda`.
Instead I want to say `std::function<...> = templated lambda`.

Comment: @byteunit Ok, so phrase your question in the form of "How do I add a lambdas as a non-static member?" That seems to have nothing to do with either the familiar template syntax for lambdas or `std::function`.

Comment: @Barry But I also need it also in other contextes, the question title is therefore correct.

Comment: @byteunit Well, what are those other contexts? This is why I'm asking what're you actually trying to do. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/297908).

Comment: @byteunit `std::function != lambda` because the first one for example is copy-constructible, but lambdas may be not, when you capture something not copy-constructible

Comment: @barry I also want to specify functions with the exact return type. And the exact return type may be the lambda.

Comment: @byteunit I don't understand what that means. Exact return type of what? "Exact return type may be the lambda" doesn't make sense - you're returning a lambda?

Comment: @barry, i sorry, with exact i mean a callable thing with the signature of `template<typename T> std::function<void(T)>` or something similar.

Comment: Lambdas have unnamed types, you *have* to use `auto` (or `decltype`). `std::function` is merely a clevery written class that can store functions/lambas, it's NOT the actual type of a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with the templated `std::function`. It's not *one* `std::function`, but *many*. The compiler will create more and more global data as you use more types.

Also, template argument deduction will not work, since the `std::function` variable is templated, not the `operator()` of the `std::function`.

Also, you don't need C++20 to have this problem, try this with C++14:

```
// equivalent to the templated lambda, just different syntax
auto t = [](auto tmp){std::cout << tmp << std::endl;};
```

> But what if I need to specify the exact type via std::function<>? (don't rely on auto).

The thing is each lambdas has a unnamed unique type that cannot be written. `auto` is the *only* way to create a variable of a lambda type.

Use `std::function` only when you need type erasure, when you need a variable of an unknown type but known interface (like a `operator()`). A `std::function` is *not free* and has *runtime* and *binary size* cost. It's a type erasure wrapper for callable type.

---

Now what if you really need the `std::function`?

Well, `std::function` can only deal with known type. For example, this will work:

```
std::function<void(int)> t = []<typename T>(T arg) { /* ... */ };
```

But will only calle the `int` version of the lambda.

Asking `std::function` to have a templated `operator()` is like asking for a virtual templated function. It cannot be implemented.

---

What if you want to use a type with a known name?

Then don't use lambdas! They may not be the tool you need!

Here's an equivalent not using auto nor `std::function`:

```
struct MyLambda {
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T arg) { /* ... */ }
};

MyLambda my_function_returning_lambda() {
    // ...
}

// ...

MyLambda lambda = my_function_returning_lambda();

lambda(1);
lambda("works");
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for the answer, that or something similar will be what I will do.
I only wanted to make sure if there is something I have not considered.